# How to write date condition on where clause in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, to-date

I have data in the date column as below.

### reportDate

21-Jan-17
02-FEB-17

I want to write a query to fetch data for 01/21/2017?

Below query not working in Oracle.

SELECT * FROM tablename where reportDate=to_date('01/21/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')

Comment: see code listing #4 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-nov/o62sql-1867727.html

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of `reportDate`? It may be DATE or VARCHAR2 and there is no way to know by just looking at it.

Run `describe table_name` (where `table_name` is the name of the table that contains this column) and see what it says.

If it's a VARCHAR2 then you need to convert it to a date as well. Use the proper format model: `'dd-Mon-rr'`.

If it's DATE, it is possible it has time-of-day component; you could apply `trunc()` to it, but it is better to avoid calling functions on your columns if you can avoid it, for speed. In this case (if it's really DATE data type) the `where` condition should be

```
where report_date >= to_date('01/21/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') 
  and report_date <  to_date('01/21/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') + 1
```

Note that the date on the right-hand side can also be written, better, as

```
date '2017-01-21'
```

(this is the ANSI standard date literal, which requires the key word `date` and **exactly** the format shown, since it doesn't use a format model; use `-` as separator and the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.)

Answer (score -1):

The query should be something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE TRUNC(column_name) = TO_DATE('21-JAN-17', 'DD-MON-RR');
```

The `TRUNC` function returns a date value specific to that column.

The o/p which I got when I executed in sqldeveloper 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/blDCw.png

Comment: Consider using `yyyy` for years instead of `RR`. While short format for years is similar and indeed shorter, it leads to bugs with dates in other centuries. We aren't that far into 21st to not have to deal with dates in 20th.